# Postgres Json_each_Text() function

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a Json column 'status' in site_request_info table with data structure as given below:

```
{
   "portStatus":{
      "status":"In Progress",
      "hrefStatus":{
         "155e4d40948647bd947fceb58131982d":"FOC Received",
         "155e4d40948647bd947fceb58131983d":"FOC Received"
      }
   },
   "broadCloudStatus":{
      "status":"Customer Created",
      "orderStatus":{
         "124260smbbTesct1188":"Order Created",
         "124260smbbTesct1188-CPE":"Order Created"
      }
   },
   "provisioningStatus":"Completed"
}
```

My Requirement is to filter the data based on HrefStatus, for that i have written query like:

```
select  * 
from product_requests p 
  inner join billing_Account b on p.account_id= b.account_id 
  inner join network_id n on b.account_id= n.account_id 
  inner join site_request_info s on n.networkid_uuid=s.networkid_uuid and s.product_request_id=p.request_id 
  **inner join json_each_text(cast(s.status->'portStatus'->'hrefStatus' as json)) d on true**
where  p.request_status='In Progress' and d.value IN ('FOC Received');
```

because of use of json_each_text() function, i am getting two rows of same data which is something i dont want my query to return.
my aim is to select all those rows having hrefStatus supplied by IN clause

I tried one alternative query but i am not able to use In clasue with this solution

```
cast(status->'portStatus'->'hrefStatus' as json)::text like '%FOC Received%'
```

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: i am using postgres12

Comment: Why the cast to `json`?  Isn't your column defined as `jsonb`? Or at least as `json`?

Comment: Thanks buddy. your solution is working. i was not aware of this syntax s.status::jsonb so used Cast function

Comment: You shouldn't cast to begin with. The column should be defined as `jsonb` not as `text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move your condition into an EXISTS condition:

```
select  * 
from product_requests p 
  join billing_Account b on p.account_id = b.account_id 
  join network_id n on b.account_id = n.account_id 
  join site_request_info s on n.networkid_uuid = s.networkid_uuid and s.product_request_id = p.request_id 
where p.request_status = 'In Progress' 
  and exists (select *
              from jsonb_each_text(s.status::jsonb->'portStatus'->'hrefStatus') as x(key,value)
              where x.value = 'FOC Received')
```

With Postgres 12 you can also use a JSON path expression:

```
and s.status::jsonb @? '$.portStatus.hrefStatus.* ? (@ == "FOC Received")'
```

Comment: This solution works but there is an issue. I aim is to get data matching the given status.Like "hrefStatus":{
                        "86264b1386174a5a987364f699538de7":"Completed",
                        "8647fc5ff8f44f479c44fc954a4b813f":"Completed",
                        "86e0af262b304041b91279524453873c":"SOA Received",
                        "daadc71b0078455abe50d6f50199511e":"SOA Received",
                        "f4c607ba5b5f4b7fade0603f7e5c7970":"Completed"
                     } from this data set i am getting completed one also even though i am passing FOC Received.